# How to specify callbacks to work with different matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib figure with multiple subplots that looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to add an interactive component to both of these subplots, such that if the user clicks on one of the nodes on the circumference, only connections to that node are displayed.

One element that is important for this task is knowing that the callback `event` has an `inaxes` attribute referring to its axes.  But that's not enough.

In order to do my task I need to store some of the plot data.  Specifically, I need to know which edges correspond to which nodes, and then retrieve that information depending on which axes the selected component belongs to.

When there is only one axes in the figure, I store this information in the closure:

```
def make_subplot():

  def _on_button_press(event, indices=None):
    # callback logic

  callback = partial(indices=indices)
  figure.mpl_connect('button_press_event',callback)
```

However, when there are multiple subplots, this does not work because either the callback gets overwritten or the indices for all plots must be stored.

My question is, what is the nicest way to do this?  The *simplest* way to do it, as far as I see, is to store a mapping of axes to subplots as a global variable, like so:

```
_indices_table = {}

def make_subplot():

  def _on_button_press(event,axes=None):
    indices = _indices_table[axes]
    #callback logic

  callback = partial(_on_button_press,axes=axes)
  _indices_table.update({axes, indices})
  figure.mpl_connect('button_press_event', callback)
```

But I am looking for a less ugly solution.  Perhaps just because of my distaste for global variables.  But I also don't want to add the overhead of a large control structure to deal with this task when a global variable would do it more simply, and more readably.

I realize I could still put this dictionary in the closure, but it is basically the same solution except worse since the callback needs to take these extra arguments that have nothing to do with the callback logic.

What is the most pythonic solution here?

Comment: I would wrap it all up in a class.

Answer (score 1):

Just save your data in an attribute of the Axe object:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def _on_button_press(event):
    ax = event.inaxes
    if ax is not None:
        print ax._my_labels

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)

axes[0]._my_labels = [1,2,3]
axes[1]._my_labels = [4,5,6]

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', _on_button_press)

plt.show()
```